# Checking flight routing before booking

Tags: air-travel

With the recent incident with a flight being shot down over Ukraine it seems like a good idea to check where flights are flying before booking.

Is there a way to tell what route a flight will take before booking the ticket?  Or something that lets you know if a flight is going to fly over a warzone or anywhere else dangerous?

Answer (score 6):

Since pilots can and do change routes all the time (based among other things on the weather and instructions from traffic control), it's impossible to know long in advance. Airlines also evaluate risks themselves and make changes accordingly.

What you could do is use some tracking system like [FlightAware](http://www.flightaware.com/) to see what route a given flight has been using in the last few days but it provides no guarantee. In fact, I heard that several airlines announced they would not fly over (part of) the Ukraine anymore (which also means that if you would have booked a ticket a few weeks ago, you might very well find yourself flying a completely different route than could be expected when booking).